# React navigation wtih redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to use react-navigation with redux in my RN app. I have a log in button with the following button press function:

```
onButtonPress() {
    const { email, password } = this.props;
      this.props.loginUser({ email, password })
      .then(() => {
        this.props.navigate('Home');
      });
    }
```

login user is an action that is dispatched by redux, this button press function however is in my login form component which I use as one of my screens in the main stack navigator, and I have tested it to make sure it works properly, however, I keep getting this error whenever I add the navigate function:
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.loginUser({  email: email,  password: password  }).then')

However, if I have the navigation statement outside of the then statement, it works. I tried looking at other questions on Stackoverflow and Git Hub but have found no solution that works, any help?

Here's what I get back when I console log (this.props):

```
Object {   "email": "n*********@gmail.com",   "emailChanged": [Function anonymous],   "error": "",   "loading": false,   "loginUser": [Function anonymous],   "navigation": Object {     "actions": Object {       "dismiss": [Function dismiss],       "goBack": [Function goBack],       "navigate": [Function navigate],       "pop": [Function pop],       "popToTop": [Function popToTop],       "push": [Function push],       "replace": [Function replace],       "reset": [Function reset],       "setParams": [Function setParams],     },     "addListener": [Function addListener],     "dangerouslyGetParent": [Function anonymous],     "dismiss": [Function anonymous],     "dispatch": [Function anonymous],     "getChildNavigation": [Function getChildNavigation],     "getParam": [Function anonymous],     "getScreenProps": [Function anonymous],     "goBack": [Function anonymous],     "isFocused": [Function isFocused],     "navigate": [Function anonymous],     "pop": [Function anonymous],     "popToTop": [Function anonymous],     "push": [Function anonymous],     "replace": [Function anonymous],     "reset": [Function anonymous],     "router": undefined,     "setParams": [Function anonymous],     "state": Object {       "key": "id-1532963235056-0",       "routeName": "Login",     },   },   "password": "******",   "passwordChanged": [Function anonymous],   "screenProps": undefined,   "signUpUser": [Function anonymous], }
```

Comment: I think your navigate is just nested in the props based on your console.log. Try:
            this.props.navigation.actions.navigate('Home');

Comment: Actually can you post more of your component code.  This could be an error with the way you are exporting the component as well.

Comment: I tried doing that but it wouldn't work, I ended up passing navigation as a prop to my action, and then navigating from there instead (helped also in distinguishing between login user fail and login user success)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
onButtonPress = async () => {
  const { email, password } = this.props;
  await this.props.loginUser({ email, password })
  this.props.navigate('Home');
}
```

Comment: I tried doing that but it would automatically login the user regardless of whether authentication was successful or not, I ended up passing navigation as a prop to my action, and then navigating from there instead which helped distinguish successful authentication